# mashup of google map,flicker,and weather.com

Tags: many-to-many

how to create a mashup of google map,weather.com and google search engine where a user can enter any location on the textbox and the map will create a bubble with the weather info and news on that entered location?

Answer (score 2):

I take it you have seen the competition referenced by this news article http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/technology/8330346.stm and now want someone to do the work for you.

Good luck finding someone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Google Maps API 2 and Google Weahter to accomplish this. Google Weather can retrieve weather info based on latitude and longitude, but you're often better off with first geocoding the lat/lng to a city and then ask the Weather API for info - I've noticed that asking Weather API with lat/lng are not that reliable at all times.

Wheather API URI example: http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Gothenburg,SE